# How to stop the message "Command "copyq onClipboardUnchanged" from popping up after removing Copyq in Linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kde-plasma

Copyq is a linux program that let you save your "copy/paste"s for future use.
I removed copyq because I've just realized that my kubuntu 20.04 version has a prebuilt clipboard app that do the same job.
After removing copyq with the terminal:

```
sudo apt remove copyq
```

I keep getting a little distracting notification message at the bottom right of the screen, it pops up almost every 5 seconds. It says exactly the following:

> **! Command "copyq onClipboardUnchanged"**
>
> Error: execve: No such file or directory
>
> 1. copyq onCkipboard Changed

Does anyone have an idea on how to stop the notification from popping up.

Thank you in advance.